# Chrome extension that runs only once

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that activates when I visit facebook. Up to this part all is good, however then it starts running my code indefinitely.

What I want is to run the content.js script only the first time I visit Facebook and then never run it again.

My current approach is this, but it doesn't work:

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.storage) {
    if (typeof request.value != 'undefined') {
      localStorage[request.storage] = request.value;
    }
    sendResponse({storage: localStorage[request.storage]});
  } else {
    sendResponse({});
  }
});
```

content.js

```
var status;
chrome.extension.sendRequest({storage: 'status'}, function(response) {
  status = response.storage;
});

if(status != '1')
{
   chrome.extension.sendRequest({storage: 'status', value: '1'});
   //  do my stuff here but only 1 time
}
```

manifest.json

```
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "js/jquery.js", "content.js" ],
      "matches": [ "https://facebook.com/" ]
   } ],
```

Basically my idea is to run content.js when I visit Facebook, then after the script is done, I add a status variable and then next time I check if the status is 1 which means that the code had already run before.

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: P.S. I answered _and_ closed as duplicate, because my other comments are slightly too big for the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are making [the standard async JavaScript mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

```
var status;
chrome.extension.sendRequest({storage: 'status'}, function(response) {
  status = response.storage; // <--+
});                          //    | This code didn't execute yet
                             //    |
if(status != '1') // --------------+
{
   chrome.extension.sendRequest({storage: 'status', value: '1'});
   //  do my stuff here but only 1 time
}
```

2) You are using a very [old and deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-sendRequest) version of [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). `extension.sendRequest`/`onRequest` need to go, replacement is `runtime.sendMessage`/`onMessage`.

3) It's best to not use Messaging here at all; [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is made specifically for this purpose. Again, maybe you're using some very old tutorial.

Comment: I used this https://gist.github.com/mohamedmansour/803631, I'll try to modify with your suggestions, thanks

Comment: @lincher I added a comment there. Do you remember how you got to that link?

Comment: I googled "chrome extension set storage from content"

Comment: hey @xan why make an answer if its a clasic js dup?

Comment: @ZigMandel I addressed that in a comment to the question. There was too much wrong at once here. I can convert the answer to a CW if you think I'm farming rep.

Comment: @xan not at all. just first time i see you do it so was curious.

Comment: @ZigMandel I haven't been dupehammer-blessed for long!